# convert a decimal to String with a specific number of bits

Tags: java, string, binary

this is the code i wrote but it has a problem some where that i don't know 
i want to convert a decimal to String but with a specific number of bits
but don't use the built in functions in JAVA

```
public static String convertToBinary(int decimal,int bits)
        {
        String binary ="";
        String need ="";
        int devision = decimal;
        while (devision != 0)
        {
            if(decimal%2==1)
            {
                devision = decimal/2;
                binary ='1'+binary;
            }
            if(decimal%2==0)
            {
                devision = decimal/2;
                binary='0'+binary;
            }
        }
        if(binary.length()<bits)
        {
            int diffrence = binary.length()-bits; 
            for(int i = 0;i<diffrence;i++)
            {
                need= need+'0';
            }
            binary = need + binary;
        }
        return binary;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here. In the while loop you need to work only with the division variable to reduce it down to zero eventually. What you have is an infinite loop because you always set `devision = decimal/2;`

Second, for appending zeros to the front you need `int diffrence = bits - binary.length();` to get a positive number.

Here's the revised:

```
public static String convertToBinary(int decimal, int bits) {
    String binary = "";
    String need = "";
    int devision = decimal;
    while (devision > 0) {
        if (devision % 2 == 1) {
            devision /= 2;
            binary = '1' + binary;
        }
        if (devision % 2 == 0) {
            devision /= 2;
            if (devision > 0) {
                binary = '0' + binary;
            }
        }
    }
    if (binary.length() < bits) {
        int diffrence = bits - binary.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < diffrence; i++) {
            need = need + '0';
        }
        binary = need + binary;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

Comment: i edited the code but the output still have some error as if the bits is 3 the output is like this :

0 = 00 
1 = 01 
2 = 010
3 = 011
4 = 100
5 = 101
6 = 110
7 = 111

Comment: @Tahany What's the issue, zero is output too short? I'm not seeing that issue when I run it. I did make a revision to not output a final leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
       **convert a decimal to String with a specific number of bits**

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int integer ;   
    System.out.print("Enter the binary Number: ");
    integer = sc.nextInt();

    int count = 0;
    while(integer>0)
    {
        count++;
        integer = integer >> 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Bits number : " +count);
```